# How do you define a vector of a vector of a vector of doubles in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I know I could or should use a 3d array but if I wanted to it with vectors, how could I do?

I know how to do it with vectors of vectors, but I can't get the right syntax for generalizing.

It should be possible.

EDIT:

I actually figured it out myself:

```
vector< vector< vector<double> > > the_vector(SIZE1, vector< vector<double>> (SIZE2,vector<double>(SIZE3,0)));
```

for a SIZE1 x SIZE2 x SIZE3 vector

Thank you.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>`.

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> vec;

Comment: Just like you define a vector of anything else: `std::vector<T>`. What is `T` for a vector of vectors? and for a vector of vectors of vectors?

Comment: you can avoid the > > > at the end of the type by using c++11. There is no  need for having the vector< vector< vector< at the beginning of the type (except if you want extra spacing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> v;
```

if you want to generalize on the number of dimensions at compile time you can create a recursive template:

```
template<int n, typename T>
struct nvect;

template<typename T>
struct nvect<1, T> {
    std::vector<T> data;
};

template<int n, typename T>
struct nvect {
    std::vector<nvect<n-1, T> > data;
};
```

used for example with

```
nvect<3, double> x;
```

With C++11 and variadic templates you can also easily create an n-dimensional fixed matrix with some of the properties you're asking:

```
template<typename T, int ...rest>
struct matrix;

template<typename T, int n>
struct matrix<T, n> {
    T data[n];
    matrix() {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            data[i] = T(0);
        }
    }
    T& operator[](int index) { return data[index]; }
};

template<typename T, int n, int ...rest>
struct matrix<T, n, rest...> {
    matrix<T, rest...> data[n];
    matrix<T, rest...>& operator[](int index) { return data[index]; }
};

template<typename T, int n, int ...rest>
matrix<T, rest...> *begin(matrix<T, n, rest...>& x) { return &x.data[0]; }

template<typename T, int n, int ...rest>
matrix<T, rest...> *end(matrix<T, n, rest...>& x) { return &x.data[n]; }

template<typename T, int n>
T *begin(matrix<T, n>& x) { return &x.data[0]; }

template<typename T, int n>
T *end(matrix<T, n>& x) { return &x.data[n]; }
```

This can be used as

```
int main() {
    matrix<double, 10, 10> m;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        m[i][i] = 1.0;
    }

    for (auto& row : m) {
        for (auto& cell : row) {
            std::cout << cell << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat. Probably going to go over his head judging by this question, though.

Comment: @6502 Hi, just came back to this answer and learned a lot - indeed it was much more than what I asked or could understand when I asked my question. I managed to implement your template and add a few functions I needed. I now would like to extend to cases where the values of each dimensions is not understood at compile time. It does seem impossible to fit inside a template design where the information needs to be known at compile time. Am I right? The only I see of doing it then is within a class. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>
```

But I am not sure what you are looking for?

Comment: It does work indeed, but what if I already know the size of each dimension and want the whole 'array' to be initialized to zero?

Comment: STL really needs multidimensional vector/array. This is pretty ridiculous. Making a multidimensional seems even more ridiculous when you consider C#'s syntax for it.

Comment: @Learningisamess Use std::array.

Comment: @Ben It's not that bad...unless you have to write out the full type. Enjoy `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > > >`